# Making a blackjack game : How to assign value to A J Q K

Tags: python

i have problem assigning value to A J Q K , how do i make python recognize J is 10? so like the output will be [5 , "J"] and Total:15 . I tried multiple ways , found this one working but its gonna take up a lot of lines

```
    if player_cards[0] == "A":
        player_sum += 11
    
    if player_cards[1] == "A":
        player_sum += 11

    if player_cards[0] == "J":
        player_sum += 10

    if player_cards[1] == "J":
        player_sum += 10
    
    if player_cards[0] == "Q":
        player_sum += 10

    if player_cards[1] == "Q":
        player_sum += 10

    if player_cards[0] == "K":
        player_sum += 10

    if player_cards[1] == "K":
        player_sum += 10
```

i used a while loop and player_sum = 0 . Is there any better way of doing this? using python btw

Comment: Use a dictionary.`{"A":11, "J":10}`, etc...
Then add dict[player_cards[0]] to the sum

Comment: You could also have each card represented as a tuple of rank, suit, and score. Or have a Card class with those attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a place to use a for loop

```
for card in player_cards:
  if card == "A":
    player_sum += 11
```

and so on. This also seems like a place to add an "or" condition, since you have a lot of repeated logic.

```
if card == "J" or card == "Q" or card == "K":
  player_sum += 10
```

[W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/default.asp) might be a good place for you to browse around to get more comfortable with the methods and functions available to you in Python. They'll give you more tools to play around with as you write code.

Comment: Seconding @MLarionov in the comments above, you could use a dictionary that mimics the switch function in other languages instead of multiple "or"s

Comment: Thanks for the solution! but i gt a new problem , i did the for loop for both my dealer cards and player cards but when i run it the player cards will always come in pairs like [2 , 2] , [J , J] and exactly same as the dealer cards

Comment: btw i tried using dict b4 but i found out that putting all the cards in a list is more easier to work with